# JPA - check if the user exists in the database by name?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i'm triying user this code

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Long> {

    @Query("select p from User p where name = ?1")
    public boolean findExistByname(String name);
    
    @Query("select p from User p where email = ?1")
    public boolean findExistByEmail(String email);
}
```

to check if the user in the database exists, but when not, it returns null and an error, I just don't know how to do this

Comment: There's a dozen different ways to solve your problem and two good ones have already popped up below. However, since you said in your problem that an error is returned, you SHOULD paste the error here so it can guide everyone's answers and help others who stumble upon the same type of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select a boolean value.

```
@Query("select count(p) = 1 from User p where name = ?1")
public boolean findExistByname(String name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    Optional<UserEntity> findByName(final String name);
}
```

and then check whether user exists:

```java
userRepository.findByName("username goes here")
                .orElseThrow(() -> new SecurityException("User not found in database"));
```

or:

```java
userRepository.findByName("username goes here").isPresent()
```